# Strategy for user-managed predicates to filter Core Data entity list

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've been thinking about this and searching for an answer for over two weeks to no avail.

I've created a form to allow a user to make selections to build a simple NSPredicate to filter a main list of entities. I want the user to be able to view the predicates they've created and to also be able to delete them if they choose. Currently, the form will allow me to get both the plain text representation of the predicate such as, "My dog is black" and the predicate string such as `"furColor == black"`.

I'm looking for a way to store these so that I can use them quickly in the NSFetchResultsController for the main entity and so I can also display them in their own table view so that they can be deleted on the fly. Does anyone know a good approach for this?

I've been thinking of keeping them in an entity table (with the plain text string and the predicate as a string or as binary data as an NSPredicate) or as a NSDictionary inside the NSUserDefaults. I'm not sure which would be better performance-wise, either to get the NSDictionary from the defaults, construct and initialize the predicates, or to fetch them from the database and then fetch the main entities.

I also hesitate to use the NSDictionary route because the order won't be guaranteed when the user views the list of predicates they've defined.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is performance really a concern yet? An array of dictionaries may match better

Answer (score 0):

The `NSUserDefaults` options seems the most practical to me. Perhaps this feature has little to do with your actual data model, so it seems wrong to mix the two. It should be very easy to use this scheme in another app.

As for sorting, you could simply add a creationDate key that you can use to sort. Or you can sort by any other key.

There should be no performance difference as long as the list of predicates is not too long (several 100 entries). `NSUserDefaults` uses an SQLite persistent store in the background which is presumably the same you are using for Core Data.

This sentence is not quite clear

> I'm not sure which would be better performance-wise, either to get the NSDictionary from the defaults, construct and initialize the predicates, or to fetch them from the database and then fetch the main entities.

You construct the predicate from the user defaults and fetch from Core Data. Don't store Core Data entities in user defaults.